# An IOexception when I try to get an InputStream connected with a file inside a jar Java Sound API

Tags: java, javasound

I am writting a simple method to play sounds using Java Sound API. My idea is to play only .wav files included in the jar. With images I can easily get an `InputStream` using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` and load an image from this stream. However, when I use the same approach with sounds, I get an `IOException`.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(InflaterInputStream.java:290)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:224)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(SunFileReader.java:59)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.WaveExtensibleFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveExtensibleFileReader.java:259)
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1010)
    at ru.mrkefir.stepan.engine.sound.Audio.playImpl(Audio.java:34)
```

The cause is `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` which I use from the following code:

```
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
     Audio.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)
);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(stream);
clip.setFramePosition(0);
clip.start();
```

I check that resulting InputStream can be read and obviously it isn't null. As I understand from the description of exception, Java Sound API and particularly the `AudioSystem` class, which I use to get an instance of `AudioInputStream`, try to use mark or reset operations on underlaying `InputStream`. Seems like these operations are not allowed on such input streams.

I am completely confused. It's strange for me that `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem` reads an `InputStream` in completely different way than `javax.imageio.ImageIO` (with `ImageIO` I can read images from a jar without problems).

How can I fix it? I may obviously read a regular file, not from the jar, but if it is possible, I want to read sounds exactly from jars.

I tried to run this code with Java 8.0.302-open and Java 16.0.2-open. Besides, if this problem is platform specific, I use Desktop Ubuntu 20.04 with Linux Kernel version 5.11.0-41-generic and, unfortunatly, I don't have an opportunity to test this code on other platforms.

**SOLVED** Thanks for @filpa, the solution is to wrap a `InputStream` obtained by `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` into `BufferedInputStream` or any other input stream which supported `mark/reset` operations.

Comment: Possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339938/991710) question and its answer. Have you tried wrapping `Audio.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)` in a `new BufferedInputStream()` (or other `InputStream` implementations which support `mark/reset`?

Comment: @filpa Thanks a lot! It turned out that the solution is ridiculously simple XD I obviously should rediscover java.io for myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to bring in sound resources is to use `getResource()` instead of `getResourceAsStream()`. There is no need to wrap in that case. If you provide a `URL` to the `getAudioInputStream()` method instead of an `InputStream`, issues/errors pertaining to mark/reset capabilities are avoided.

There are examples posted at Stackoverflow's [info area for the javasound tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). Basically:

```
URL url = YourClass.class.getResource("youraudio.wav");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

The above assumes the audio resource is in the same folder as the class YourClass.

P.S. If you prefer the answer (using `getResourceAsStream()` and wrapping, please actually write this as an answer, and select it. Otherwise this question will lure in people who like to help others, thinking this question has not yet been answered. Alternatively, invite @filpa to post his info as an answer and select it.

Comment: I would always recommend using `getResource()`, besides JavaSound knowing how to handle the (wrapped) streams, there is the *possibility* that the `Clip` is cached. If it was started with an URL, it won't need to be reloaded.

Comment: Thanks @Phil Freihofner and AndrewThompson! I understand what you wanted to say. The choice which solution should I pick is worth think about. In my particular case, I am writting a very-very simple  game engine based on Java Swing, generally, for internal educational purposes. As soon as I am preparing this material for first year students, I guess the performance is not important. However, thanks again for helping, I will think about the choice for my own development. I will mark this answer as a solution to not bother filpa.

Comment: A game loop is a great idea for a project for students! FWIW, there might be some member-written articles and code at jvm-gaming.org using Swing, from the years before JavaFX and LibGDX/LWJGL came to be used, that can be consulted for ideas (in their "Articles and Tutorials" section). Best of luck with your teaching! If @filpa takes the initiative to provide his answer as an answer, please feel free to switch you answer designation. The main point: thanks for updating the status of this question.

Comment: FWIW I'm completely fine with this, together with @AndrewThompson's comment, being the accepted answer as it offers far more insight than my comment (which was technically inappropriate in lieu of a duplicate vote) does.

Comment: *"Otherwise this question will lure in people who like to help others, thinking this question has not yet been answered."* Huh .. I recommend marking answers as accepted for the benefit of those *looking for answers* later. For my part, I may get a a list of 20 hits on a problem - but will look only at listings with the green tick!